# Почему при обращении к участникам, пропадает знак собачка @

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

Уже не в первый раз, когда я набираю перед именем участника форума знак собачка,  чтобы обратиться к ним, сразу после публикации поста исчезает и знак собачка и само имя, остается только сам вопрос.

В чем проблема? Может, я что-то делаю не так? Обычно, когда набираешь знак собачки и хочешь написать имя, система уже при первых же буквах сама тебе выдает имя. Как сделать, чтобы так было всегда?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Серж, если вы комментируете сообщение и обращаетесь к его автору, то не надо ставить @. (Она, если поставлена, всё равно автоматически убирается.)

Это связано с тем, что сисвол @ нужен для того, чтобы система отправила уведомление вашему адресату. Если же вы комментируете чье-то сообщение, то автору и так приходит уведомление, поэтому @ был бы лишним.

Comment: Aer, подскажите, пожалуйста, если в комментариях к ответу участвуют только автор ответа и один комментатор, то имя комментатора тоже можно ставить без @? Я как-то заметил некоторые подобные закономерности, но оказалось, что не все они верны. Теперь сомневаюсь тоже во всех.

Comment: @grizzly другого комментатора все равно надо отмечать с помощью @.

Comment: Нет, комментатор один. Я автор ответа. Тогда мне не нужно ставить @?

Comment: @grizzly нужно.